# Combine 3 sequences

Tags: linq

I have three string arrays. I want to combine them using zip in linq. How to do?

```
arr1.Zip(arr2, (a1, a2) => a1 + a2);
```

How to add arr3?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Zip again:

```
arr1.Zip(arr2, (a1, a2) => new { a1, a2 })
    .Zip(arr3, (a12, a3) => a12.a1 + a12.a2 + a3)
```

or

```
arr1.Zip(arr2, (a1, a2) => a1 + a2)
    .Zip(arr3, (a12, a3) => a12 + a3)
```

The former version avoids one extra string concatenation.

Comment: 173K?? Is that 173 or 173,000? Looks like i can close my eyes and follow your suggestion superman :) Is that link i posted also containing the right answer?

Comment: @As: Yes, the link is doing basically the same as the second of my snippets.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using a custom Zip which takes as many sequences as you need.

```
public static IEnumerable Zip(
    this IEnumerable first,
    IEnumerable second,
    IEnumerable third,
    Func resultSelector )
{
    Contract.Requires(
        first != null && second != null && third != null && resultSelector != null );

    using ( IEnumerator iterator1 = first.GetEnumerator() )
    using ( IEnumerator iterator2 = second.GetEnumerator() )
    using ( IEnumerator iterator3 = third.GetEnumerator() )
    {
        while ( iterator1.MoveNext() && iterator2.MoveNext() && iterator3.MoveNext() )
        {
            yield return resultSelector( iterator1.Current, iterator2.Current, iterator3.Current );
        }
    }
}
```

This is basically [Jon Skeet's implementation](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/14/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-35-zip.aspx) with one extra parameter, so all credit goes to him. ;p I believe this has [some advantages in some scenarios](http://whathecode.wordpress.com/2011/04/05/zip-multiple-sequences-together/), where you would otherwise need intermediate objects. I definitely find it clearer.